# How to create a role with superuser in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I am new to postgres. I want to create role 'KRM' as SUPERUSER. But I am facing the below issue. When I try to create, it mentions that it already exists, But when I try to drop the role, it says that the role does not exist. Any help is appreciated.

```
edb=# CREATE ROLE "KRM" LOGIN ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'KRM' SUPERUSER CREATEDB CREATEROLE REPLICATION VALID UNTIL 'infinity';
ERROR: role "KRM" already exists
edb=# drop role KRM;
ERROR: role "krm" does not exist*emphasized text*
```

Comment: `krm <> "KRM"` https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS

Comment: Also, `KRM` <> `"KRM"`.